# Got stuck with multiple value validation against in particular columns in awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file where i'm trying to validate with particular column(5) if that column contains value like ACT,LFP,TST and EPO then file goes to further process else it should be exit.Here i'm if my text file contains these value in column number 5 means ACT,LFP,TST and EPO go for further process on other hand if column contains apart from that four value then script will terminate.

Code

```
cat test.txt \
  | awk -F '~' -v ERR="/a/x/ERROR" -v NAME="/a/x/z/" -v WRKD="/a/x/b/" -v DATE="23_09_16" -v PD="234" -v FILE_NAME="FILENAME" \
    '{ if ($5 != "ACT" || $5 != "LFP" || $5 != "EPO" || $5 != "TST")
        system("mv "NAME" "ERR);
        system("rm -f"" "WRKD);
        print DATE" " PD " " "[" FILE_NAME "]" " ERROR: Panel status contains invalid value due to this file move to error folder";
        print DATE" " PD " " "[" FILE_NAME "]" " INFO:  Script is exited";
        system("exit");

}' >>log.txt

Txt file: test.txt(Note:- File should be processed successfully)

161518~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~ACT~UD
010282~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~ACT~UD
162794~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~LFP~UD
030767~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~LFP~UD

Txt file: test1.txt(Note:- File should not be processed successfully.This file contains one invalid value)

161518~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~**ACT1**~UD
010282~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~ACT~UD
162794~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~TST~UD
030767~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~LFP~UD
```

Comment: Your i/p file doesn't even have 10 columns?

Comment: @Inian thanks i did mistake now i have corrected.

Comment: Your approach seems to be right? do the processing only when the `if` condition matches

Comment: Glad you went with only 5 columns data to illustrate your problem! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: awk is not shell. awk is a tool to manipulate text, shell is an environment from which to call tools and manipulate files/processes. Don't try to use shell to manipulate text and, in this case, don't try to use awk to manipulate files. This is clearly a job for a simple shell command.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

Lets assume the following input file:

```
010282~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~ACT~UD
121212~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~ZZZ~UD
162794~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~TST~UD
020202~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~YYY~UD
030767~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~LFP~UD
987654~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~EPO~UD
010101~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~XXX~UD
123456~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~TST~UD
```

**1)** This example illustrates how to check for invalid lines/records in the input file:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    FS = "~"
    s = "ACT,LFP,TST,EPO"
    n = split( s, a, "," )
}

{
    for( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        if( a[i] == $5 )
            next

    print "Unexpected value @ line " NR " [" $5 "]"
}

# eof #
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk -- input.txt 
Unexpected value @ line 2 [ZZZ]
Unexpected value @ line 4 [YYY]
Unexpected value @ line 7 [XXX]
```

**2)** This example illustrates how to filter out (remove) invalid lines/records from the input file:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    FS = "~"
    s = "ACT,LFP,TST,EPO"
    n = split( s, a, "," )
}

{
    for( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        if( a[i] == $5 )
        {
            print $0
            next
        }
    }
}

# eof #
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk -- input.txt 
010282~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~ACT~UD
162794~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~TST~UD
030767~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~LFP~UD
987654~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~EPO~UD
123456~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~TST~UD
```

**3)** This example illustrates how to display the invalid lines/records from the input file:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    FS = "~"
    s = "ACT,LFP,TST,EPO"
    n = split( s, a, "," )
}

{
    for( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        if( a[i] == $5 )
            next

    print $0
}

# eof #
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk -- input.txt 
121212~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~ZZZ~UD
020202~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~YYY~UD
010101~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~XXX~UD
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: LOL, hey... `awk to the rescue` is a registered trademark ;-). Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the calls to system, this will show you an answer.

```
awk -F"~" '{ if (! ($5 == "ACT" || $5 == "LFP" || $5 == "EPO" || $5 == "TST")) print $0}'  data.txt
```

**output**

```
161518~CHEM~ACT~IRPMR~**ACT1**~UD
```

This version is testing if `$5` matches at least one item in the list. If it doesn't (the `!` at the front of the `||` chain tests), then it prints the record as an error.

Of course, `$5` will match only one from that list at a time, but that is all you need.

By contrast, when you say

```
if ($5 != "ACT" || $5 != "LFP" ...)
```

You're creating a logic test that can never be true. If $5 **does not equal** "ACT" because it is "LFP", you have already had the chained condition fail, and the remaining `||` will not be checked.
IHTH